# Falha de Router no CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Estou atualizando um site que foi feito em **Cake Php** e estou com problema de **Rota**.
Em `app\config\routes.ctp` estão as regras abaixo e esse funciona:

```
Router::connect( 
    '/curia/anuario', 
    array( 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'anuario' ) 
);
```

Esse abaixo não funciona:

```
Router::connect( 
    '/curia/teste', 
    array( 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'teste' ) 
);
```

Outros não funcionam
Os arquivos estão em `app\views\pages`
Dentro de pages eu tenho `anuario.ctp` e tenho `teste.ctp`
`teste.ctp` não funciona, da erro 404.
Existe algum outro lugar onde deve ser configurado?

Comment: Como está seu arquivo PagesController ?

Comment: você criou as `actions`(métodos) no controller `PagesController`?

Comment: você deve criar o método `teste` no controller definido na rota.